# Check data watermark at different steps via the Dataflow API

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In the Dataflow UI, I can check the data watermark at various steps of the job (ex. at step GroupByKey, the data watermark is 2017-05-24 (10:51:58)). Is it possible to access this data via the Dataflow API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the gcloud command line tool to access the API.

```
gcloud beta dataflow metrics list <job_id> --project=<project_name>
```

Look for metrics ending in data-watermark

```
F82-windmill-data-watermark
```

However, this is not yet easy to understand since the naming is based on an optimized view of the dataflow graph, not the view of the pipeline graph that the code and UI look like. It also uses identifiers like FX.

It might be best to take all the data-watermarks and grab the minimum value, which would show the oldest timestamp for elements not yet fully processed by the pipeline.

What information are you looking for in particular?

See:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataflow/

Comment: Thank you. I'm particularly looking for the data watermark at the last step of the job, which writes to a sink. I would guess this would be the same as the minimum watermark. It sounds like I can reference cbt (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigtable/cmd/cbt/cbt.go) to figure out how to access this information via a Go app. This is something I'd be monitoring routinely to make sure the job is "keeping up" with streaming data.

Comment: You may also consider taking a look at this blogpost if you are interested in adding alerts for these metrics

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/03/monitoring-and-improving-your-google-cloud-dataflow-pipelines-with-google-stackdriver